# Image Table in HTML

Tags: html, wordpress, image, tabular

I want to do exactly like this for my self-hosted wordpress site - http://www.dota2.com/heroes/

I assume they put separate pictures in a table (could be completely wrong)

Any suggestions on where should I start ?

Comment: Study WordPress first. Hire somebody able to do it for you. period.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This is not the way to ask questions here. If you do not ask specific questions with examples of what you tried, your question will be downvoted and closed as off topic

Comment: To give you a hint - right-click and view source. You will see they are not using tables at all but simple divs full of icons that have the same width and height. Each link has a hidden companion that is displayed or hidden using CSS hover

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you check the source code you can see that they are using DIV to place the element like they want. You can do it with a table too if you want (it could be easier!).

If you want to do it "exactly like them" you can make a container with a fixed width, and they insine you could add your images with a fixed width.

I would also advise you to check "Source Code" ! It will be very helpful (I think)!
(If you are using chrome as main navigator : https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/181951?hl=en)

#### Hope it helped you

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid table. From my experience, tables are hard to work with.
I would rather go with `<ul><li></li></ul> or <div class="container"><div class="pic"></div></div>`

The `<li></li>` or `<div class="pic">` will have float:left so that they get rendered one after another.

If you feel that the data you are rendering are actually a table, then only table makes sense.
Your data is not a table with multiple columns.